# State Error C2440:" '=': cannot convert from 'const FDHNode<ItemType> *' to 'FDHNode<ItemType> *'"?

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error "C2440:"   '=': cannot convert from 'const FDHNode *' to 'FDHNode *" and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Here is my code and the defining function where the issue is coming from apparently.

```
template<class ItemType>
class FDHNode
{
  private:
    ItemType coeff; //Data item representing coefficient
    ItemType expon; //Data item representing exponent
    FDHNode<ItemType>* next; //Pointer to a next node 
  public:
    FDHNode();
    FDHNode(const ItemType& coeffi, const ItemType& expone);
    FDHNode(const ItemType& coeffi, FDHNode<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
    void setCoeffi(const ItemType& aCoeffi);
    void setExpon(const ItemType& anExpon);
    void setNext(const FDHNode<ItemType>* NEXTPTR);
    ItemType getCoeffi();
    ItemType getExpon();
    FDHNode<ItemType>* getNext();

    void print();


 };

template<class ItemType>
void FDHNode<ItemType>::setNext(const FDHNode<ItemType>* NEXTPTR)
{
    next = NEXTPTR;
}
```

Comment: You have a const pointer and want to assign it to a non-const pointer. That doesn't work, as it would allow you to later modify what is const.

Comment: How would you suggest I fix this? I am trying to define a function for a Node class so it points to the next node. @BoPersson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `next` is defined like so:

```
FDHNode<ItemType>* next; //Pointer to a next node
```

And the variable `NEXTPTR` is defined like so:

```
const FDHNode<ItemType>* NEXTPTR
```

The added `const` has its significance, in stating that it cannot be modified. When you're assigning `NEXTPTR` to `next`, it becomes a problem because `next` could be modified, but `NEXTPTR` is a constant.

There are two ways in which this could be resolved, depending on certain things:

1. If the `next` pointer is something that could in fact be changed, you then have to modify the definition of `NEXTPTR` such that it's not a `const`. If you do this, your function declaration would like so: `void FDHNode<ItemType>::setNext(FDHNode<ItemType>* NEXTPTR)`
2. Or the parameter really is a constant, in which case you should define your `next` variable as a `const` as well. Like so: `const FDHNode<ItemType>* next;`

Note: There's `const_cast<>` which could cast away the `const`-ness of a variable. But if you didn't know the answer to this question, it's unlikely that you need that cast here as it could do more harm than good in such a case.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your first suggested solution by making it not const worked perfectly.

Comment: @FrancisHeroux I'm glad it worked, and I more importantly do hope that you understood the problem.

Comment: I did, it was painstakingly obvious that I was contradicting myself once you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

It is said very clear in the error, `NEXTPTR` is `const FDHNode<ItemType>*` while `next` is `FDHNode<ItemType>*`, you can not assign `const FDHNode<ItemType>*` to `FDHNode<ItemType>*`.

You can use `const_cast` to make it `non-const`, for example:

```
FDHNode<ItemType>* non_const_next = const_cast<FDHNode<ItemType>*>(NEXTPTR);
```

And the best way to do it is to change the parameter of `setNext()`, change it to `FDHNode<ItemType>* NEXTPTR`